# Use WHERE filter in dynamics AOT Query

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, aot

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT
TT.RECID,
TT.TRANSDATE,
TT.DATAAREAID,
TT.SOURCERECID,
TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,
TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
GJAERIVA.TEXT,
GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE,
GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71,41)
WHERE   
(TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2016-06-30'  AND '2017-06-30') OR (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30' )
```

All my query is right except for `WHERE` clause, how can I apply where clause using Query AOT?

In this [article](https://blog.fullscope.com/2016/08/02/aot-queries-get-more-complex-than-you-think) they apply where clause but they don't explain how they do it.

Current query

[image]

> Note: If something is wrong with my question please let me know what
>   is it. Regards

Comment: The article you linked does explain it a bit (starting at the paragraph that starts with "How can this be done?"), but fails to mention that this technique is commonly referred to as "query expressions". They are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa893981.aspx), but I prefer the [Axaptapedia article](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges).

Comment: The information from the linked Axaptapedia article will help if you're creating the query in X++. You can use that if you append the range to your AOT query object after declaring it in the same code where you want to use it. 
If you must do everything in the AOT, then you will need to change the structure of your query to join two buffer of TaxTrans table in order to satisfy the OR clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new range to data source TaxTrans_1 - you can use field `RecId`, it doesn't matter. Then you can use the following value in this range:

```
((TaxOrigin != 11) && (TransDate >= 30\06\2016) && (TransDate <= 30\06\2017)) || ((TaxOrigin == 11) && (TransDate >= 02\06\2017) && (TransDate <= 30\06\2017))
```

See [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges) for more details and examples.